# Автоматические scope namespace в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как можно автоматически делать scoped-namespace в файле после добавления `;` к неймспейсу? Т.е неймспейс будет с `{ }`, но как только я добавлю `;` после слов `namespace MyNamespace` они автоматически станут scoped. Знаю, что это на 100% возможно.

Comment: Да не через `;` это делается, а через рефакторинг `Ctrl+.`

Comment: @aepot у меня на работе можно и через рефакторинг, и через `;`. Только не понимаю как это сделано.

Comment: Хм, действительно, `;` работает. / Сравнить версии дома и на работе. Сравнить установленные extensions. / А ещё можно настройки экспортировать/импортировать. С рабочего компа перенести на домашний. Конечно, дома старые забэкапить на всякий случай.